# Pandas how to set column to NaN based on values in other columns using .loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` on which I'm calling a function to fill NaN in columns where the condition isn't met.

Following is my code:

```
def clean_feedback(DF):
    feed_id = DF.id_y.unique()
    for ID in feed_id:
        Min = np.argmin(np.abs(DF[DF.id_y == ID].created_at_x - DF[DF.id_y == ID].created_at_y))
        print(Min)
        DF[DF.id_y == ID].loc[DF[DF.id_y == ID].index != Min, 'comments'] = np.nan
        return DF[DF.id_y == ID]
```

Sample Dataframe is:

```
id_x    user_id merchant_id amount_spent    bill_number created_at_x    checked_in  chain_id    id_y    feedback_setting_id comments    created_at_y    updated_at  feedback_type
1097    268868  975 42  149 None    2016-12-14 12:11:14 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
2150    468876  975 42  278 None    2017-06-04 10:51:47 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
6535    5020    975 42  200 None    2015-03-25 12:37:36 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
9228    476314  975 42  676 None    2017-06-09 14:34:03 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
9601    293308  975 42  438 None    2017-01-22 13:03:18 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
10215   781647  975 42  335 None    2017-08-21 13:36:43 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
20405   5441    975 42  200 None    2015-03-29 14:24:32 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
24117   277853  975 42  220 None    2016-12-25 12:57:53 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
24432   949216  975 42  219 None    2017-10-05 10:22:52 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
24475   289288  975 42  109 None    2017-01-15 08:49:55 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
32318   767980  975 42  293 None    2017-08-16 09:41:30 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
32820   343502  975 42  387 None    2017-03-22 12:52:48 1   NaN 219 194 Lovely cafe!    2017-03-22 12:55:05 2017-10-05 06:45:49 1
```

Whenever I call the function:
`clean_feedback(Transaction[Transaction.id_y == 219])`, there aren't any changes. I'm sure its a stupid mistake but im completely stumped.

EDIT1: I've also tried doing the about with `.where` function, but it makes the entire dataframe NaN. Is there any way to specify for the column `comments`?

Comment: Have you tried: `DF.loc[(DF.id_y == ID) & (DF.index != Min), 'comments'] = np.nan` ?

Comment: `DF[DF.id_y == ID].loc[DF[DF.id_y == ID]` why did you do that twice?

Comment: because I wanted to make nan for only that specific id, not all other entries in that column

Comment: jpp, you comment worked! Please post this as an answer and I'll upvote it! Thanks. Also could you give me an explanation on why my code wasn't working ?\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DF.loc[(DF.id_y == ID) & (DF.index != Min), 'comments'] = np.nan
```

**Explanation**

- [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts label-based *or* Boolean indexing.
- Your 2 desired criteria are for `id_y` to equal `ID` and `index` != `Min`.
- The `&` operator combines 2 Boolean series to form a single Boolean indexer